What is the meaning of "一片月", "一片日"?
My question is somehow similar to
What does the measure word 一片 mean? and how to use it?, but I post a new question, to be more specific.
"片" being a measure word, "一片" is usually translated as "a piece of", "a slice of".
Referred to the sun or the moon, this pretty confuses me.
Do they mean:

"a complete piece of", "an integer", "full" ("一片月": there's a full moon ; "一片日": the complete circle of the sun is clearly visibile; graphically: ︎ ), or

"just a part of" ("一片月": a crescent, only a part of the moon is visibile; "一片日": just a part of the solar disk, maybe at sunset or sunshine; graphically: ☾ )


?
Update
Here are a couple of examples from works by 李白:

长安一片月
(From 《子夜吴歌·秋歌》)


孤帆一片日边来
(From 《望天门山》)

Update to previous update
The last example is out of topic: As pointed out by @kyc and @r13, in it, "一片" refers to "孤帆"

Where did you see 一片月 and 一片日 though? I’ve never seen such usage (except 长安一片月，万户捣衣声) so honestly I can’t tell the meaning without the context.

Ah I saw your update! Actually in 孤帆一片日边来, it’s 一片孤帆 instead of 一片日.

@kyc : yes,  My mistake!

Two additional explanations of "片":

延伸至/遍佈于广阔的平面或广阔区域 (stretch; something spread over an extended plane or vast area)


长安一片月 - a stretch of moon(light) in Chang-An

Similar phrases - 一片死寂 (dead silence); 一片哀號 = 遍地哀號 (Wailing everywhere)

形容薄而成片的东西 (describe something thin and flaky)


两岸青山相对出，孤帆一片日边来。- Agree with @pingan Cheng, here, 一片 modifies 孤帆.


In daily usage a measure word describes the amount or quantity of something, which refers to its literal meaning. In poetry, however, the use of a measure word has certain literature function, which readers might need to dig in. Every word contributes to the general conception of the verse. Here I put my search result about the appreciation of your two examples.
In 《子夜吴歌·秋歌》赏析, 一片 is like in a range of

长安一片月，万户捣衣声
Tonight the moon shines across all of Chang'an, Tens of thousands of homes resound with the pressing of winter garments;

Here 一片 describes 月 / 月色 / moonlight. 一片月 indicates the imaginal status of the moonlight. Households are doing laundry at the same time (万户捣衣) in an unified moonlight (一片月). What a purely peaceful image in my (Li Bai's) eye.
In 《望天门山》赏析, 一片 is like a slice of

两岸青山相对出，孤帆一片日边来。
Verdant mountains unfold themselves slowly, at my left and right, As my solitary sail drifting afar from where the sun is arise.

Here 一片 decorates 孤 / solitary in 孤帆. The mountains, the sail, the sun compose the image altogether, celebrating the self-motivated, goal-directed brave sailsman.

一片月：一片皎洁的月光。
长安一片月
秋月皎洁长安城一片光明，
(The) autumn moon makes 西安市 a sea of light,
万户捣衣声
家家户户传来捣衣的声音。
(The) pounding of clothes can be heard from every household.

不是很熟悉这两首诗，但是根据古诗文网，一片月指的是“一片月光”。
“孤帆一片日边来”，这里“一片”我觉得是用来修饰“孤帆”的，即一片孤帆。
